# Sending retrieved data from database as an array to php file

Tags: php, ajax

first file:

```
$data = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $data[] = $row["input"]; // make sure that db table column name is `input`
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

second file:

```
function retrieveData(){
    $.post('quick.php',{}, function(data){
        var new_data = $.parseJSON(data); // decode json data and covert it to jquery array

        $.each(new_data, function(index, element) { // iterate over array
            window.alert(element); // alert each element of the array
        });
    });
}
```

I am trying to send the data I get from the database to another PHP file as an array but it is not working. Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: Is your "first file" the `quick.php`?

Comment: yes  my "first file" is the quick.php

Comment: Are you sure that you get a json from your php file? Maybe the `$result->num_rows > 0` will result in `false`.

Comment: yea I am getting the data in retrieveData function I try to window.alert (data) and it worked but when I tried window.alert (new_data) it does not worked. I think the problem is in    var new_data = $.parseJSON(data); but I do not know why @mapek

Answer (score 0):

you make and ajax request but i don't see the success and the error section you should try this

```
    $.ajax({                
                url: 'quick.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {},
                success: function (data)
                        {                        
                          var new_data = $.parseJSON(data); // decode json data and covert it to jquery array

            $.each(new_data, function(index, element) { // iterate over array
               window.alert(element); // alert each element of the array
            });  
                        },
                        error: function(json){

                                //Manage the error here
                            }


});
```

Comment: still not working as I test it. it works correctly till var new_data = $.parseJSON(data); I have even tried to alert new_data to see if it works correctly, but it does not alert with anything

Comment: OK first you have to make sure the json_encode($data) in quick.php return something. Have tested it?

Comment: yea I test it all way through the retrieveData() function I have my data but here is where i have a problem var new_data = $.parseJSON(data); I do not know why . I have even try to alert new_data but it does not worked

Comment: Sorry for responding late. What do you get when make alert(data); ?